# Select Most Common Opponent for each Player

Tags: sql-server

I have a player game history table that lists all the chess games a player has played at tournaments.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cub_player_hist](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [player_id] [int] NULL, --Player's ID
    [Event_Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Event_id] [int] NULL,
    [Event_Start] [smalldatetime] NULL, 
    [FullName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, -- Player's Name
    [Result_txt] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [result] [int] NULL,
    [played_id] [int] NULL, -- Opponent's ID
    [Played] [nvarchar](max) NULL, -- Opponent's Name
 CONSTRAINT [cub_player_hist_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I'd like to create a View that will count the number of times the played_id for each player_id and select the most frequently occurring for each played_id.

If a View is the wrong way to go about this then I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Have you considered normalising cub_player_hist?

Maybe you're not allowed to - but if you can then the following tables (assuming multiple pairs can play at one event?)

- Player
- Event
- Match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test following SQL script where I used **[multiple-CTE in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)**

For counting games for the player for his/her all matches, and counting for each opponent, you can use [SQL COUNT() function with Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx)

As the last step, to select the most frequently played opponent for a player, we can use [SQL Row_Number() function with Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) clause

```
;with cte as 
(
    select *,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by player_id) cnt_all,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by player_id, played_id) cnt_opp
    from [dbo].[cub_player_hist]
), cte2 as (
    select
        *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by player_id order by cnt_opp desc) rn
    from cte
)
select 
    player_id,
    fullname player_name,
    played_id,
    played opponent_name
from cte2 
where rn = 1
order by player_id
```